# How to output string lines from a file by using recursion and streams in Java

Tags: java, recursion, input, stream

```
sldls slfjksdl slfjdsl
ldsfj, jsldjf lsdjfk
```

Those string lines are from a file called "input".

How to ouput those string lines in reverse order to a file called "ouput" by using input, output stream and recursion in Java?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is this homework? Otherwise I would use a library to read/write file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to put the entire code here but I will put segments from each key areas and hopefully you will figure out to put everything together.

Here is how you should reverse the given string

```
public static String reverseString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
 int length = is.available();
 byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
 int ch = -1;
 while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
  bytes[--length] = (byte) ch;
 }
 return new String(bytes);
}
```

This is how your main method should look like calling the above function.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
String reversedString = reverseString(is);
```

And finally hopefully you fill figure out how to write to a file by playing around with this.

```
  try{
  // Create file 
  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("/Users/anu/GroupLensResearch/QandA/YahooData/L16/out.txt");
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
  out.write(reverseRead(is));
  //Close the output stream
  out.close();
  }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an example of Java best practices, but it works and should be enough to get you started

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("infile.txt"), "UTF-8");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("outfile.txt");
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, "UTF-8");  
    recurse(scanner, outputStreamWriter);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
static void recurse(Scanner scanner, OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter) throws IOException {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (scanner.hasNext())
        recurse(scanner, outputStreamWriter);
    outputStreamWriter.write(line + "\n");
}
```

The second encoding argument to Scanner and OutputStreamWriter can be dropped if you're using your system's default encoding.